# Is there a name for the type of shorthand sentence that excludes yourself as the subject? e.g., "Going to the park."

Tags: subjects, construction

See this all the time. Doing it right now. Leaving out the "I am" piece of the sentence. Does this have a name?

Comment: It's called pronoun dropping.  We do it in  résumés all the time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an example of ***pro drop*** (short for *pronoun dropping*).

Some languages, like Spanish,  pretty much mandate it. Such languages are called ***[pro-drop languages](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-drop_language)***.

In English, most grammarians would probably consider it ungrammatical, but it's pretty standard in informal speech.

Regarding its occurrence in English, Wikipedia writes:

> English is considered a non-pro-drop language. Nonetheless, subject pronouns are almost always dropped in imperative sentences (e.g., *Come here*). **In informal speech, pronouns may sometimes be dropped in other types of sentences**...
>
> - [*Have you*] ever been there?
> - [*I'm*] going to the shops. [*Do you*] want to come?
> - Seen on signs: [*I am/We are*] out to lunch; [*I/we will be*] back at 1:00 [*P.M*].

The second and third examples of this passage are precisely the kind of sentences you ask about. These sentences can be called ***pro-dropped sentences***.

Note, however, that pro dropping can occur for *any* pronominal subject, not just for "I". For example, consider the following dialogue:

> **A**: Where's Ingmar?
>
> **B**: Went home.

Here, the pronoun "he" is being dropped.

As a final note, these kinds of pro-dropped sentences fall under the more general umbrella of ***[ellipsis](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/ellipsis)***:

> the omission from speech or writing of a word or words that are superfluous or able to be understood from contextual clues.

Comment: Bravo! upvote..